# Ionic how to setup iOS SDK and deployment target

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, deployment

in these days apple is requiring to use the iOS 12.1 SDK or later. 
In my Ionic 3 app I have configured the deloyment target for ios 9 in the config.xml file.
Can I also configure the desired SDK here? because I use Ionic Pro for auto builds so it's necessary.

Any idea ? Thanks in advance.